# Why does Chrome always open on the last virtual desktop I had it open on?

Tags: google-chrome, kde, virtual-desktop, kde-plasma-5, kde-plasma-workspace

I've been having incredibly annoying behavior with Chrome on KDE for a while now.  (A couple years, maybe?)

Generally, if I launch an app, it opens up on the virtual desktop I'm on.  But for some reason Chrome as of late will open itself on the last desktop it was on, and change me to that desktop.  It feels super violating.  Like, If I'm on virtual desktop 5 and open Chrome, it opens on virtual desktop 3 and takes me there.  If I move it to virtual desktop 6 and close it, then go to some other desktop, like 2, and reopen it, it'll re-open on virtual desktop 6 and take me there.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening or what to do about it, and none of my searches (here or on the wider web) are getting me any closer.  I can't tell if it's a weird KDE/Plasma "feature" (I hate it and consider it a bug), or if Chrome is at fault.  I tried setting KDE "Special Application Settings" and "Special Window Settings", but I can't figure anything out through any of that either.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?  And more importantly, how I can set Chrome/KDE/Plasma to always just open everything on the virtual desktop I'm on?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Chrome on a Unix environment, so this is kind of a shot in the dark.  Chrome 97.0.4692.99 behaves this way on Windows 10 Home virtual desktops if **Settings > On Startup > Continue where you left off** is set.  If I change to either **Open the New Tab page** or **Open a specific page or set of pages**, then Chrome starts on the current desktop.

An  alternative might be to leave one Chrome window always open (perhaps minimized) so that closing the window you are working in does not exit.